# How count leaf elements in xml file in java

Tags: java, xml

I want to count all *leaf* elements in an xml file in Java. Suppose my xml structure is like the example below, I want to count all `name` and `id` elements in this file. How do I do this?

Xml Sample:

```
<set>
 <employee>
    <name> </name>
    <id></id>
 </employee> 
 <employee>
     <name> </name>
     <id></id>
  </employee>
</set>
```

Attempted Java Code:

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(file.toFile());
    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
    if (!root.hasChildNodes()) {
        paths.add(file);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Element Name in: "+file.getFileName());
        System.out.println("Root element: " + "Total count: " + root.getChildNodes().getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = root.getChildNodes().item(i);
            if (node.getChildNodes().getLength() != 0) {
                System.out.println("name: " + node.getNodeName() + " size:"+ node.getChildNodes().getLength());
            }
        }
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: And how is the code not working?

Comment: See [answer by VGR](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35069296/5221149), with my comment to adjust to updated question (counting leaf elements vs. counting named elements).

Answer (score 4):

***NOTE:*** This answer is about counting the number of elements with particular known names (`name` and `id`). Question has been changed to request counting leaf elements, which this answer does not cover.

To perform a full depth-first search of an XML document, you have a choice of methods.

If you only need to perform the search, and nothing else, then a [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html) parser is the best choice, for both performance and memory footprint.

Otherwise a [DOM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/when.html) parser is likely your best choice.

If you don't want to traverse the XML tree yourself, you can use [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html) to do it for you.

Here is an example of all three, with test code:

```
private static int countUsingStAX(String xml) throws XMLStreamException {
    int count = 0;
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(xml));
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        int event = reader.next();
        if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
            String name = reader.getLocalName();
            if (name.equals("name") || name.equals("id"))
                count++;
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    return count;
}

private static int countUsingDOM(String xml) throws Exception {
    int count = 0;
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = domBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    Node node = document.getDocumentElement();
    while (node != null) {
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            String name = node.getNodeName();
            if (name.equals("name") || name.equals("id"))
                count++;
        }
        if (node.getFirstChild() != null)
            node = node.getFirstChild();
        else {
            while (node != null && node.getNextSibling() == null)
                node = node.getParentNode();
            if (node != null)
                node = node.getNextSibling();
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private static int countUsingXPath(String xml) throws XPathException {
    String xpathExpr = "//*[self::name or self::id]";
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = factory.newXPath();
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate(xpathExpr,
                                                 new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)),
                                                 XPathConstants.NODESET);
    return nodeList.getLength();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String xml = "<set>\r\n" +
                 " <employee>\r\n" +
                 "    <name> </name>\r\n" +
                 "    <id></id>\r\n" +
                 " </employee>\r\n" +
                 " <employee>\r\n" +
                 "     <name> </name>\r\n" +
                 "     <id></id>\r\n" +
                 "  </employee>\r\n" +
                 "</set>";
    System.out.println(countUsingStAX(xml));
    System.out.println(countUsingDOM(xml));
    System.out.println(countUsingXPath(xml));
}
```

All three print the number `4`.

DOM traversal could also be done using recursion, e.g. using `getChildNodes()`.

Comment: if i don't know node element child name how count it?in here i don't know that child name is id and name.

Comment: @hadiJZ You *said* you wanted to count the number of `name` and `id` elements. Did you actually mean that you wanted to count the number of *leaf* elements? If so, please edit question to clarify.

Comment: I am sorry :(. yes i want to count leaf element. and in xml file i don't khon leaf element name. ie the leaf elements name are defferent.

Answer (score 4):

[XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is the best way to do this.  You can use two slashes in an XPath expression to search at all levels:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//name|//id", document, 
    XPathConstants.NODESET);
int count = nodes.getLength();
```

**Update:**

Now that the question is asking how to count leaf elements regardless of the element name, the XPath expression should be:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//*[not(*)]", document, 
    XPathConstants.NODESET);
int count = nodes.getLength();
```

Comment: XPath is definitely the shortest/easiest way to do it, but since question has been updated to clarify that OP want to count number of *leaf* elements, the expression should be `"//*[not(*)]"`, meaning any element that doesn't have any children.

Comment: @Andreas Right you are.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at this article: [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-count-xml-elements-in-java-dom-parser/)

The gist of it is this:

```
String filepath = "c:\\file.xml";
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
```

Then get your count:

```
System.out.println("Total of elements : " + list.getLength());
```